# jQuery .html() won't fit in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="site-loader"><body></body></div>

//Takes in HTML string. 
function processData(data){
    console.log(data);
    self.vue.html_data = data
    //$('#site-loader').contents().find('body').html(data);
    $("#site-loader").html(data);
}
```

I'm loading an external site (say like Amazon.com) and trying to place it in the site-loader div. I don't care how big any site is, but I want to restrict the size of the loaded site into a fixed size that's determined by the styling of my site-loader div.

Editing the css of the site-loader div doesn't change anything about the loaded site. Any ideas?

Essentially, I want to display any site into a small fixed frame that can be scrolled around to view the displayed site.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about an `iframe`. Note however than many sites do not like being placed in those (or being scraped at all).

Comment: you cannot have the body tag like this

Comment: Far too many unknowns for anyone to provide constructive help here

Comment: Restricting a div to a given size seems to me to reflect a css max-width and max-height rule along with an overflow: auto

Comment: Thank you @Taplar ! Overflow solved it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the size of an element by providing a max width and height with an overflow.

```css
#container {
  background-color: rgb(16, 16, 16);
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#largeChild {
  min-width: 2000px;
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="largeChild"></div>
</div>
```